# Accelerating slow MySQL import using python connector

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I'm writing a python script which imports a large database into MySQL. So far I used this approach, and it works, but it is slow:

```
importdb = "mysql -h " + DB_HOST + " -u " + DB_USER + " -p" + shlex.quote(DB_USER_PASSWORD) + " " + DB_TARGET + " < " + os.getcwd() + "\\AllPrintings.sql"
os.system(importdb)
```

According to [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98814/mysql-dump-import-incredibly-slow-on-my-developers-machine) and similar posts, import can be faster if default settings are changed before import:

```
SET autocommit=0;
SET unique_checks=0;
SET foreign_key_checks=0;
# <import statement here>
COMMIT;
SET unique_checks=1;
SET foreign_key_checks=1;
```

The issue is that those settings are relevant only for specific connection. As I am using python script, I see two options, and in both I am failing to find a working solution:

1. Use os.system and add SET commands - I tried to separate commands with ; but it seems to stop executing them after first ;

> #doesn't work

```
importdb = "mysql -h " + DB_HOST + " -u " + DB_USER + " -p" + shlex.quote(DB_USER_PASSWORD)+ "; " + "use " + DB_TARGET + "; SET autocommit=0; SET unique_checks=0; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; " + "source" + os.getcwd() + "\\AllPrintings.sql; SET autocommit=1; SET unique_checks=1; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;"
os.system(importdb)
```

2. Use import mysql.connector and add import statement: SET commands work, but not importing

> #doesn't work

```
cur.execute(f"SET autocommit=0;")
cur.execute(f"SET unique_checks=0;")
cur.execute(f"SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;")
cur.execute(DB_TARGET + ' < ' + os.getcwd() + '\\AllPrintings.sql')
conn.commit()
cur.execute(f"SET autocommit=1;")
cur.execute(f"SET unique_checks=1;")
cur.execute(f"SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;");
```

I'm stuck and I don't know how to move further, all help will be appreciated...

---

**EDIT & SOLUTION**

On the basis of @mrrobot.viewsource answer below, the solution was to modify imported db with commands above. It decreased importing time of test database from 73 min to 2 min. My code:

```
with open(os.getcwd() + "\\AllPrintings.sql", "r+",encoding="utf8") as f:
        content = f.read()
        f.seek(0, 0)
        f.write("SET autocommit=0;\nSET unique_checks=0;\nSET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" + '\n' + content)

with open(os.getcwd() + "\\AllPrintings.sql", "a+", encoding="utf8") as f:
    f.write("\nSET unique_checks=1;\nSET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. Did you try printing the variable importdb ?
Here is what is happening in your script:

**PROBLEM:**

Your script (commented `os.system(importdb)` for obvious reasons):

```
import shlex
import os

DB_HOST="1.1.1.1"
DB_USER="root"
DB_USER_PASSWORD="password"
DB_TARGET="somedb"

importdb = "mysql -h " + DB_HOST + " -u " + DB_USER + " -p" + shlex.quote(DB_USER_PASSWORD)+ "; " + "use " + DB_TARGET + "; SET autocommit=0; SET unique_checks=0; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; " + "source" + os.getcwd() + "\\AllPrintings.sql; SET autocommit=1; SET unique_checks=1; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;"
print(importdb)
#os.system(importdb)
```

The output:

```
mysql -h 1.1.1.1 -u root -ppassword; use somedb; SET autocommit=0; SET unique_checks=0; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; source/some/path\AllPrintings.sql; SET autocommit=1; SET unique_checks=1; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

From the output:

1. the first `;` i.e. `mysql -h 1.1.1.1 -u root -ppassword;` makes the control go to the MySQL client shell and you are no longer with python here which answers your below query.

> but it seems to stop executing them after first ;

2. If you check the output `source/some/path\AllPrintings.sql;` - There should have been space between source and filename.
3. The `SET` commands must be present inside your `AllPrintings.sql` file as in:

```
# <AllPrintings.sql - start of file>

SET autocommit=0;
SET unique_checks=0;
SET foreign_key_checks=0;

# <your_queries in the sql file>

COMMIT;
SET unique_checks=1;
SET foreign_key_checks=1;

# <AllPrintings.sql - end of file>
```

**SOLUTION:**

Add the `SET` commands in the AllPrintings.sql file itself as mentioned in Point 3 and change your `importdb` variable as below

```
importdb = "mysql -h " + DB_HOST + " -u " + DB_USER + " -p" + shlex.quote(DB_USER_PASSWORD)+ " -D " + DB_TARGET + " < " + os.getcwd() + "\\AllPrintings.sql"
```

That should work for you.

Comment: Thank you! Modifying the DB decreased import time from 73 minutes to 2 min. I will edit my question with the final code.

To spread karma further, you can send me a link to any charity and I will donate 10 eur on your behalf ;-)